# Is a Loading label / notification on link click / redirect necessary?

Tags: notification, loading

**Is a Loading label / notification on link click / redirect necessary?**

Nowadays if I click a link the only sign that something is happening or processing is that the favicon on the tab changes into a loading icon. If I remember correctly browsers used to change the mouse cursor to `wait`.

Anyway my concern is . . When the page is responding slowly the tendency is users that did not notice the loading icon on the tab would spam click a link which would lead to:

> click->cancel request->create new request->click->cancel
>   request->create new request->click

Which would technically take even longer for a page to load.

SO should a more noticeable notification be implemented like maybe a **Loading** at the top or bottom of the screen? Or just leave it as is?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "Loading" mention is the simplest thing to implement because it is plain text. If it is technically possible, you might consider a progress bar. If the calculations for a real progress bar are not practical, consider an [indeterminate progress bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=indeterminate%20progress%20bar&biw=1314&bih=876&tbm=isch&imgil=J91i2kIK2yXdKM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcR3Vw2LkXOvnGYQM2hN6NyQn0HRdP6DXkMSfC9sIQjaAF04e3Eu%253B270%253B123%253Bhz0f0TGpvCQUYM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.uxguide.net%25252Fwiki%25252Fmacos%25253AIndicators&source=iu&usg=__Ihze7YpukqaIxdVgISGF2feVmoU=&sa=X&ei=sRB6U6KnO8eV7AaRjoB4&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAQ#facrc=_&imgrc=J91i2kIK2yXdKM%253A;hz0f0TGpvCQUYM;http%253A%252F%252Fstorage.uxguide.net%252Fwiki-imgs%252Fmacos%252Fct_indetermprogexample.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.uxguide.net%252Fwiki%252Fmacos%253AIndicators;270;123).

To answer your question "is it necessary," that depends on how long a response time you are talking about. You might find the following study of interest: http://cba.unl.edu/research/articles/548/